# Execute SQL queries through POST

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have setup a custom setting page and have added a field under the following section

```
add_settings_field("delete-commands", "Delete Commands", "delete_commands", "demo", "section");
register_setting("section", "delete_commands");
```

Would like to execute the delete_commands function when the delete button is submitted

[image]

The following code didn't delete the orders after submitted and the setting page is refreshed. Wondering what went wrong, thanks.

```
function delete_commands()
{
  global $wpdb;
  ?>
  <form method="post">
   <input class="btn" style="float:none;" type="submit"  name="delete" value="Delete all orders"  />
 </form>

  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        //global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix;
        $wpdb->query(
          "DELETE  FROM {$table_name}_woocommerce_order_itemmeta;
           DELETE FROM  {$table_name}_woocommerce_order_items;
           DELETE FROM  {$table_name}_comments WHERE comment_type = 'order_note';
           DELETE FROM  {$table_name}_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT ID FROM  {$table_name}_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' );
           DELETE FROM  {$table_name}_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order';
      ");

    }
}
```

Comment: First print all query then see and try to execute directly to mysql what error came and also as in you first and second query there is no where clause so what you want to delete ?

Comment: Which setting page? how do you call delete_commands()  function? Your question is just unclear actually. You should add in your question the other related code…

Comment: Hi guys, thanks I have added a few more description so it's clearer.

Comment: Try : if ( isset($_REQUEST['delete']) ) {

Comment: Thanks @GNANA but it didn't work either. No idea. what's wrong